# Probability that your return is positive for the week, given its distribution per year

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics

You make an investment. Assume that returns are normally distributed with a mean return of .20 **per year** and a standard deviation of .10. Suppose you check on your returns once a week. What is the probability that your return is positive **for the week**? We define the ratio of noise to performance as the coefficient of variation (the ratio of the standard deviation to the mean). Calculate the number of parts of noise per part performance if you check your returns once a week. In this problem, you can assume that weekly returns are independent of each other.

I've bolded what's throwing me off -- the "per year" vs "for the week."

Comment: I think you are to assume that every week is like any other, and therefore the weekly returns have the distribution of (annual return)/52.

Answer (score 1):

You are expected to assume that the weekly return is also a normal distribution.  Leaving aside compounding, the average weekly return is $\frac {0.20}{52}$  We know that the variance of a sum is the sum of the variance, so compute the variance of the annual return from the standard deviation, divide by $52$ to get the weekly variance, then compute the weekly standard deviation.  You should find much more noise in weekly data than yearly data.

Comment: Thanks! When you say "the variance of a sum is the sum of the variance," I'm not exactly sure where any summing comes into play. Which formula would that be -- central limit?

Comment: You are summing the performance of each week to get the performance for the year.  Since you know the variance over the year, this lets you find the variance of a week.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply! So if i'm understanding correctly, you're saying just to take it over 52 too to get the per week variance. so std dev = .1, then var = .01 for the year. Per week, the variance would be .01/52 and std dev would be √(.01/52)?

Comment: That is correct.  Now you note that on the annual basis the return is twice the standard deviation but on the weekly basis it is smaller.